Applying shadows in react native through external package by alan eu
I am applying shadows to a box using a package I downloaded from
https://github.com/alan-eu/react-native-fast-shadow
But I am not able to get the shadow to move to the behind of the object.
Here I tried applying a shadow as shown below. The shadow is coming over the box instead of going behind it.
<ShadowedView style={{
  shadowOpacity: 0.1,
  shadowRadius: 12,
  shadowOffset: {
    width: -10,
    height: 0,
  }
}}>
          <View style={[styles.item, styles.card]}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight:600, color:"rgba(11, 88, 141, 1)"}}>text</Text>
            <View style={styles.bottomrow}>
              <Text style={{ paddingRight: 20 }}>text</Text>
              <Text style={{ color: "#FA0000" }}>text</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

</ShadowedView>

The color of the box background is
rgba(227, 234, 255, 0.3)

normally i use this code to apply shadow in Android and ios:
  elevation: 3; //this is only for Android
  background-color: #fff;
  shadow-color: rgba(227, 234, 255, 0.3);
  //try to play with these 3 shadow values bellow to adapt to your need
  shadow-offset: -2px 4px; 
  shadow-opacity: 0.2;
  shadow-radius: 3px;

